# Logarithmic inequality using its definition

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

I'm having some problems with proving this inequality using logarithmic definitions.

For any $i \in \mathbb Z^+$, show that

- $\frac{1}{i+1} \le \ln(i+1) - \ln(i) \le \frac{1}{i}$

Hence, use your result to prove that for any $n \in \mathbb Z^+$,

- $\ln(n+1) \le 1 + \frac{1}{2} +...+ \frac{1}{n} \le \ln(n) + 1$

For the first part, I got $\frac{1}{i+1} \lt \frac{1}{i}$ and so, the results of their integrals will be $\ln(i+1) \gt \ln(i)$. Thus, $\frac{1}{i+1} - \frac{1}{i} \lt \ln(i+1) - \ln(i)$. However after this part, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: How could $\ln(n+1)\le \ln n$ hold?

Comment: Ah you're right, I made a mistake there. I edited it, added a '+ 1' to the back of ln(n). Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: $\verb*\ln*$ yields $\ln$ instead of $ln$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the inequality you want to show is
$$ \ln(n+1)\le \sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{i}\le\ln n+1. \tag{*}$$
In fact, using
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n(\ln(i+1)-\ln(i)\le\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i $$
one has
$$ \ln(n+1)\le\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i. \tag1$$
Using
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1{i+1}\le\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(\ln(i+1)-\ln(i)$$
one has
$$ \sum_{i=2}^n\frac1{i}\le\ln n $$
or
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{i}\le\ln n+1. \tag2 $$
(1) and (2) together give (*).